# Ubuntu 12.04 lost data?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, grub2

My Ubuntu 12.04 suddenly rebooted after working great for a month. I checked and saw that all my downloads,installed programs and bookmarks are gone. It looks like a fresh installation all together.

I wanted to check what the issue is but I can't become root:

```
guest-EelhlO@paddington-MS-7327:~$ sudo -s
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [117, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
```

I cannot even ping in the terminal:

```
guest-EelhlO@paddington-MS-7327:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logged in as a guest (`guest-EelhlO@paddington-MS-7327`). Login within your username and you will find your data. The guest account will not allow you to use `sudo` for instance.